# ExecutiveAlign error: atomic alignment failed (mismatched identifiers? )

Tags: rna

So I have a molecule (a dsRNA) , that has two conformations. I want to align it in pymol with molecules but I get the following error: ExecutiveAlign error: atomic alignment failed (mismatched identifiers? )

So I try removing the conformations and maintain the spaces also, however no luck. INfact after editing and displaying the sequence in pymol, the chain ids seem to get interleaved as follows:
[image]
I am writing here sample text from the molecule that has both the conformations:

ATOM      1  O3'A  C C   1      -7.005  37.688  50.581  0.60 29.09           O
ATOM      2  O3'B  C C   1      -6.653  36.261  51.094  0.40 28.26           O
ATOM      3  P  A  C C   1      -8.284  38.506  50.584  0.60 27.34           P
ATOM      4  P  B  C C   1      -8.150  36.411  51.318  0.40 28.35           P
ATOM      5  O1PA  C C   1      -8.747  38.916  51.969  0.60 27.60           O
ATOM      6  O1PB  C C   1      -8.852  35.063  51.303  0.40 26.74           O

and the molecule after removing the conformers, editing the identifier number, and maintaining the spaces as found in usual PDB files:

From chain C:
ATOM     1  O3'   C C   1      -7.005  37.688  50.581  0.60 29.09           O
ATOM     2  P     C C   1      -8.284  38.506  50.584  0.60 27.34           P
ATOM     3  O1P   C C   1      -8.747  38.916  51.969  0.60 27.60           O
ATOM     4  O2P   C C   1      -8.241  39.648  49.584  0.60 28.40           O
ATOM     5  O5'   C C   1      -9.442  37.507  50.040  0.60 28.29           O

From chain D:
TER    446        U C  21
ATOM   447  O3'   C D   1     -11.398  37.360  86.614  0.60 24.03           O
ATOM   448  P     C D   1     -11.903  36.706  87.889  0.60 26.14           P
ATOM   449  O1P   C D   1     -12.702  37.680  88.743  0.60 28.36           O

Please help, at the end of the day I would like to align this molecule with other molecules in pymol without getting the error. Thanks